# How to check multiple page types in PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm developing a woocommerce shop and what I'm trying to do is, to show the product lists only at the category and search result page, but not at the shop page, which is marked in the woocommerce settings.

I'm wrapping the content of the product lists inside of this code:

```
<?php if( is_product_category() ) : ?>

<div id="nm-shop" class="nm-shop <?php echo esc_attr( $shop_class ); ?>">
....
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This solution, works so far that the product lists, only shows at the category pages, but how can I extend the if function to another variable? The problem that I have right now is, that the search result pages, shows no results, because it's not a category page.

I tried to add it like this `<?php if( is_product_category(), is_search() ) : ?>` so that the result page is included, but all I'm getting is a WordPress error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, by the following code:

```
<?php if( is_product_category() || is_search()) : ?>
```

Comment: That was quick.

Comment: Sometimes you hang on to something for several hours without coming up with the answer, and shortly after the despair it occurs to you.

I'll leave the question anyway, maybe it will help someone in the future.